# VBA excel to word replace and insert text in the same document

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I'm a VBA beginner and o want to replace text and add new one line on the same open word document. But i have tried this piece of code but id doesn't work.

```vb
    Sub open_word_replace_text()
    
    Dim book1 As Word.Application
    Dim sheet1 As Word.Document
    
    Set book1 = CreateObject("word.application")
    book1.Visible = True
    
    Set sheet1 = book1.Documents.Open("Template.docx")
    
    With sheet1.Content.Find
       .Text = "prova"
       .Replacement.ClearFormatting
       .Replacement.Text = (Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value) & " " &      (Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value)
       .Wrap = wdFindContinue
       .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
       .Forward = True
    End With
    
    'the following part must be write after the replace as new line on the      word document and same paragraph
 
     sheet1.Content.Text = (Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value)
    
    end sub
```

Could you please someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

I don't find a solutions

Comment: Please check your question esp. the code part. I tried to fix the formatting - but there are some line breaks missing ...

Comment: Sorry, I fixed. Now the code is more clear. Thank you

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Is there any error? What's your expected result?

Comment: `as new line on the word document and same paragraph` Is it a new paragraphy at the end of the doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.TypeText method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.typetext?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663163)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Selection.EndKey method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.endkey?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663161)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub open_word_replace_text()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
'    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("Template.docx")
    ' The more reliable way to open file
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.docx")
    With wdDoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchCase = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = "prova"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = Sht.Range("A2").Value & " " & Sht.Range("B2").Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    'the following part must be write after the replace as new line on the word document and same paragraph
    With wdApp.Selection
        .EndKey Word.wdStory
        .TypeParagraph ' Inserts a new blank paragraph
        .TypeText Sht.Range("C2").Value
    End With
'    wdDoc.Save
'    wdDoc.Close
'    wdApp.Quit
End Sub
```

---

Update:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub open_word_replace_text()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
'    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("Template.docx")
    ' The more reliable way to open file
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.docx")
    With wdDoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchCase = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = "prova"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = Sht.Range("A2").Value & " " _
            & Sht.Range("B2").Value & _
            Chr(13) & Sht.Range("C2").Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your code i try to run but the behavior is not what i expect. I try to explain better. The first part of the code replace right prova with excel range content. But after the second part (Witj wdApp.Selection) append the text at the end of the document, but i want to append new line of text below the the replaced one not in the end of the document. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi here it is Exactly what i wanted! Thank you so much!